# SUM of Activity History for ACCOUNT

Tags: map

I need to Count Number of Activities of Account and place that Number of activities in visualforce page using table.

I have already created a MAP

**CONTROLLER**

```
public Map<Integer, Account> getabc()

{

for( Account accountObj : [SELECT (SELECT Id FROM ActivityHistories) FROM Account where Referring_Contact__c in : contactIdList])

{

if(mapActivityHistoryCountToAccount.containsKey(accountObj.ActivityHistories.size()))

{

mapActivityHistoryCountToAccount.put(accountObj.ActivityHistories.size(), accountObj);

}

}

return mapActivityHistoryCountToAccount;

}
```

**VF PAGE**

```
<apex:pageblocktable value="{!abc}" var="item1">

                            <apex:column headerValue="Number of Activities">
                                <apex:outputText value="{!abc[item1].size}">
                                </apex:outputText>
                            </apex:column>
</apex:pageblocktable>
```

Please somebody Help me to resolve this

Comment: Can you share more detail of what you tried so far, the VF page and controller/extension for example would be helpful.

Comment: Please see my controller and vf page. if it is not correct then let me know what mistake i have made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest the simpler approach of returning the raw data to the page:

```
public List<Account> getAbc() {
    return [
            select Name, (select Id from ActivityHistories)
            from Account
            where Referring_Contact__c in :contactIdList
            order by Name
            limit 1000
            ];
}
```

and then just referencing the child list size in the page:

```
<apex:pageblocktable value="{!abc}" var="item">
    <apex:column value="{!item.Name}"/>
    <apex:column headerValue="Number of Activities">
        <apex:outputText value="{!item.ActivityHistories.size}"/>
    </apex:column>
</apex:pageblocktable>
```

(The above is untested.)